# Javascript Undefined error and variable scope

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I'm a bit tired and I can't see why I'm getting `undefined` errors on the variable `cat.data[0].id`.

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
      function Trial() {
          var index = 0;
          var cat = [];
          
          function getcat() {
                  .
                  .Makes a call to get JSON set of data in the form
                  .{"status" : "success", "data" : [{"id":"8", "url":"http:\/\/google.com", "description":"Search Engine"}]}
                  .
                  request.success(function (data) {
                    cat = $.parseJSON(data);
                    if (cat.status === "error") {
                        alert(cat.message);
                    }
                    console.log(cat.data[index].id);
                    alert(cat.data[0].id);
                  });
                  request.error(function (data, status) {
                    alert("Error connecting to API:" + status);
                  });
              }
          }
          
          function tests() {
            getcat();
            console.log(cat.data[index].id);
          }
```

So when we call tests function it pulls the data and puts into array and the entries for `console.log` and alert do exactly as they should and display the id field value. However when it returns to tests and does the `console.log` entry there it fails with:

> "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference"

It's a global variable in the master function so why isn't it able to access it?

Comment: Try logging out just cat and look at the structure.

Comment: Yes I have done that and it is correct. The problem is that the function tests doesn't seem to be able to see cat...? which is weird as it can see index!

Comment: Well, you have a typo in the function name first off. `getcats();` should be `getcat();` in the `tests` function.

Comment: It can access `cat` but it seems like `cat` doesn't have a `data` property on it, i.e. `cat.data` is undefined.

Comment: It's because cat is an empty array until after you get the data back in the callback of the request.

Comment: Sorry that was typo when copy and pasting - Editied.

Comment: When you would do `console.log(cats)`, you would see it is an empty array, since none of the response code has executed yet. The `success` callback runs later than your test `console.log`. Read about asynchronous code in JavaScript and the referenced duplicate questions.

Comment: OK - I was wondering that as some of the tests did show the output in a odd order. So when getcats() is being executed it moves onto the console.log ?

Comment: trincot would be right - the array is empty. That was my gut instinct. Thanks

Comment: So I tried adding this: var check = getcats(); having aded some return code to the getcats() function which I believe should make it synchronise but the same issue happens?